# Best way to monitor PHP Errors from logs

Tags: php, logging

So we all have PHP error logs and we all have to check them.
Is there anything built out there that can look at a PHP error log and see if its different to last time and email the differences or something?

It would save so much time every day, especially when there are lots of servers. PHP errors are especially delicate because often we need to respond to them asap.

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/httpd/*.php.error.log` ?

Comment: this is how i currently do it, but its annoying for all of the servers, also when there are no changes to the log for many days sometmes (no errors :))

Comment: No errors for many days! What a lucky sonofabitch! :) I am mighty jealous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well if I were you, and there are indeed no errors for many days to show, I'd just set up some cron job to check if error file is empty and send it's last 50 lines by email if not

Comment: I think ill go for a cron that moves these to a database (that way i can see them accross many servers)